# Auto sign in to newly downloaded app from login saved from website registration

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an ionic 3 application where I want to be able to have a user register on a website > have a default login and password saved on their device > then when they download the app, it automatically logs them in.

Is that possible, or even reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible if all the users login will all be the same because you can save to something like database but if you want to have default login details generated after being registered in your website I think it is not possible for "me". You must have some logic that will sync to your app